# WPF MVVM Case: ItemsControl contains hyperlink and command to update property in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a case, a little bit more complex but I try to illustrate and do some modification to show the point in a simple way.

Let's say I have a Window1 as view and a Window1ViewModel as its viewmodel. I also have a SubMenuViewModel class to represent submenu in the window. I want to make an ItemsControl in Window1 which contains many submenus. Every time user clicks one of the submenu, the property CurrentSubMenu updates to the corresponding submenu. This is the problem, I can't manage to update the CurrentSubMenu in the *Window1ViewModel*.

.

**SubMenuViewModel :**

```
public class SubMenuViewModel : INPC
    {
        private string _submenuname;
        public string SubMenuName 
        {
            get
            {   return _submenuname;   }
            set
            {
                _submenuname = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SubMenuName");
            }
        }
        private string _displayname;
        public string DisplayName 
        {
            get
            {   return _displayname;   }
            set
            {
                _displayname = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DisplayName");
            }
        }

        // Command for Hyperlink in ItemsControl //
        private RelayCommand _commandSubmenu;
        public RelayCommand CommandSubMenu 
        {
            get
            {   return _commandSubmenu;   }
            set 
            {
                _commandSubmenu = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CommandSubMenu");
            }
        }
        // end of command

        public SubMenuViewModel(string Submenu_name, string Display_name)
        {
            _submenuname = Submenu_name;
            _displayname = Display_name;
        }
    }
```

**Window1 :**

```
<Window x:Class="SomeProject.Window1"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SomeProject.ViewModel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="This is Some Project" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:Window1ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Name="SubMenuPanelBorder"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="15 0 15 0"
                BorderThickness="2"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Padding="10 10">

            <HeaderedContentControl Content="{Binding Path=SubMenus}" Header="Panel Submenu :">
                <HeaderedContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent" Margin="0 15">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock>
                                        <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=CommandSubMenu}">
                                            <TextBlock Margin="0 5" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                                        </Hyperlink>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HeaderedContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </HeaderedContentControl>

        </Border>

        .......
        .......

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window1ViewModel :**

```
class Window1ViewModel : INPC
    {
        private List<SubMenuViewModel> _submenus;
        public List<SubMenuViewModel> SubMenus 
        {
            get
            {   return _submenus;   }
            set
            {
                _submenus = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SubMenus");
            }
        }
        private SubMenuViewModel _currentSubMenu;
        public SubMenuViewModel CurrentSubMenu
        {
            get
            {   return _currentSubMenu;    }
            set
            {
                _currentSubMenu = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentSubMenu");
            }
        }

        public Window1ViewModel()
        {
            SubMenus = MenuDefinition.GetSubMenus();

            /*** 
            Set the SubMenus's command to update the CurrentSubMenu,
            and == HERE IS WHERE I GOT LOST ==. 
            The CurrentSubMenu is always point to the last submenu in the loop when clicked. 

            By the way, the reason I use loop is because the submenu in the Menu definition sometimes changed and there are many number of submenus there, and there are some other reasons (I use Menu-submenu mechanism, but it's not essential to show it here because it's not the main point I want to show). So, finally I use loop instead of specifying each command one by one.  
            ***/

            foreach(SubMenuViewModel submenu in SubMenus){
                submenu.CommandSubMenu=new RelayCommand(()=>clickedSubMenu(submenu.SubMenuName));
            }
        }

        public void clickedSubMenu(string submenu_name)
        {
            CurrentSubMenu = SubMenus.Find(sub => sub.SubMenuName == submenu_name);
        }
    }
```

**MenuDefinition :**

```
public static List<SubMenuViewModel> GetSubMenus()
        {
            return new List<SubMenuViewModel>
                    {
                        new SubMenuViewModel("overview_product", "Overview Products"),
                        new SubMenuViewModel("search_product","Search Products"),
                        new SubMenuViewModel("update_product","Update Data Products"),
                        new SubMenuViewModel("order_product","Order Products"),
                        new SubMenuViewModel("supplier_product","Products Supplier"),
                        .................
                        .................
                        .................
                    };                        
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple thing, but somehow it takes a little bit time for me to find this. I have to add a temporary variable before it's passed to the delegate action of RelayCommand. With that way, the RelayCommand's delegate "*Action execute*" will take the correct parameter and point to the correct submenu. and of course not always the last submenu.

Back in the **Window1ViewModel** :

So, instead of directly using the submenu.SubMenuName property like this

```
// This way, when clicked, the command will always point to the last submenu from the loop
public Window1ViewModel()
        {
            SubMenus = MenuDefinition.GetSubMenus(); 

            foreach(SubMenuViewModel submenu in SubMenus){
                submenu.CommandSubMenu=new RelayCommand(()=>clickedSubMenu(submenu.SubMenuName));
            }
        }
```

We have to add some temporary variable like this.

```
// This way, when clicked, the command will point to the correct submenu
public Window1ViewModel()
        {
            SubMenus = MenuDefinition.GetSubMenus();

            foreach(SubMenuViewModel submenu in SubMenus){
                string Temp=submenu.SubMenuName
                submenu.CommandSubMenu=new RelayCommand(()=>clickedSubMenu(Temp));
            }
        }
```

And the output will be different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your binding properties should be written like this.

```
private string _Terminal;
    public string Terminal
    {
        get
        {
            return _Terminal;
        }
        set
        {
            _Terminal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Terminal");
        }
    }
```

Make sure viewmodel implement INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            propertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is Terminal? do you mean CurrentSubMenu in the Viewmodel?

Comment: I've added RaisePropertyChange() in every setter in ViewModel, but still the same.

Comment: Your viewmodel also has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for this to have effect

Comment: yes, I've added it, too..I'm using Josh's MVVM Foundation. RaisePropertyChanged() definition is packed inside. But still..

Comment: Are the display name's showing up and the commands just not relaying?

Comment: the displayName is showing up, but not the submenu I clicked. The CurrentSubMenu is set to the wrong submenu. It's set to the last loop of submenu (refer to the Window1ViewModel).

Comment: ok so have you put breakpoint in setter of CurrentSubMenu?  It either not hit, hit with wrong value, or the CurrentSubMenu binding is not working

Comment: Yes, it reaches the CurrentSubMenu for the breakpoint (both getter and setter are okay). I think maybe there is something wrong with the loop because CurrentSubMenu always refers to the submenu in the last loop when clicked

Comment: Finally, I find the solution for this.